# Failed assertion: line 49 pos 16: 'initalPageIndex <= (imagesLink.length - 1) && initalPageIndex >= 0': is not true.)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm Trying To Show A Slider Using The Following Package `fan_carousel_image_slider 0.1.2`

Full Error Text:

> _AssertionError ('package:fan_carousel_image_slider/src/image_slider.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 49 pos 16: 'initalPageIndex <= (imagesLink.length - 1)
> && initalPageIndex >= 0': is not true.)

I Tried To Change Attributes And Images Sizes But Without Any Result.

```
import 'package:fan_carousel_image_slider/fan_carousel_image_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Outlet());
}

class Outlet extends StatelessWidget {
  const Outlet({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Outlet',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        primaryColor: Colors.red[800],
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  static List<String> sampleImages = [
    "assets/images/Sample (1).jpg"
        "assets/images/Sample (2).jpg"
        "assets/images/Sample (3).jpg"
        "assets/images/Sample (4).jpg"
  ];

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FanCarouselImageSlider(
              imagesLink: MyHomePage.sampleImages,
              isAssets: true,
              autoPlay: true,
            ),  
   ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Static keyword and move the list to below _MyHomPageState class:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {

  List<String> sampleImages = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557700836-25f2464e845d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=627&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669462277329-f32f928a4a79?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542840410-3092f99611a3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FanCarouselImageSlider(
        imagesLink: sampleImages,
        isAssets: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Got Another Error 
"The getter 'sampleImages' isn't defined for the type 'MyHomePage'.
Try importing the library that defines 'sampleImages', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'sampleImages'."

Comment: update your post with your updated code. Or try the code that I commented.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:fan_carousel_image_slider/fan_carousel_image_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Outlet());
}

class Outlet extends StatelessWidget {
  const Outlet({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Outlet',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        primaryColor: Colors.red[800],
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  static List<String> sampleImages = [
    "assets/images/Sample (1).jpg"
        "assets/images/Sample (2).jpg"
        "assets/images/Sample (3).jpg"
        "assets/images/Sample (4).jpg"
  ];

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
int get initialPage => 1;
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
*SizedBox(
                height: 190,
                width: 400,
                child: FanCarouselImageSlider(
                  imagesLink: MyHomePage.sampleImages,
                  isAssets: true,
                  autoPlay: true,
                  expandedImageFitMode: BoxFit.fill,
                  expandedCloseBtn: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_circle_left_rounded,
                    color: Colors.red.shade500,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  indicatorActiveColor: Colors.red,
                  autoPlayInterval: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
                  sliderHeight:
                      170, //MUST Be Less Than The Sized Box height By 20.0 p
                  sliderWidth: 400,
                ),
              ),*
   ],
 ),
```

-Solved By Creating Defined Size SizedBox Instead Of Just Being Part Of The Column
-And Setting The Initial Page Index To Start From 1